# Spark on Windows - What exactly is winutils and why do we need it?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm curious! To my knowledge, HDFS needs datanode processes to run, and this is why it's only working on servers. Spark can run locally though, but needs winutils.exe which is a component of Hadoop. But what exactly does it do? How is it, that I cannot run Hadoop on Windows, but I can run Spark, which is built on Hadoop?

Comment: Among other things, it seems like Spark uses Hadoop which calls unix commands such as chmod to create files and directories.

Comment: You cannot fully run Spark if you grab the Hadoop distro. You cannot read and write files without winutils.

Comment: Yes, Spark is built upon Hadoop, so it makes sense for it to use some of its components. Also, you cannot do certain operations without winutils.exe, the question was mainly about what's in this winutils.exe? What purpose does it have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know of at least one usage, it is for running shell commands on Windows OS. You can find it in `org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell`, other modules depends on this class and uses it's methods, for example `getGetPermissionCommand()` method:

```java
static final String WINUTILS_EXE = "winutils.exe";
...
static {
  IOException ioe = null;
  String path = null;
  File file = null;
  // invariant: either there's a valid file and path,
  // or there is a cached IO exception.
  if (WINDOWS) {
    try {
      file = getQualifiedBin(WINUTILS_EXE);
      path = file.getCanonicalPath();
      ioe = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOG.warn("Did not find {}: {}", WINUTILS_EXE, e);
      // stack trace comes at debug level
      LOG.debug("Failed to find " + WINUTILS_EXE, e);
      file = null;
      path = null;
      ioe = e;
    }
  } else {
    // on a non-windows system, the invariant is kept
    // by adding an explicit exception.
    ioe = new FileNotFoundException(E_NOT_A_WINDOWS_SYSTEM);
  }
  WINUTILS_PATH = path;
  WINUTILS_FILE = file;

  WINUTILS = path;
  WINUTILS_FAILURE = ioe;
}
...
public static String getWinUtilsPath() {
  if (WINUTILS_FAILURE == null) {
    return WINUTILS_PATH;
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException(WINUTILS_FAILURE.toString(),
        WINUTILS_FAILURE);
  }
}
...
public static String[] getGetPermissionCommand() {
  return (WINDOWS) ? new String[] { getWinUtilsPath(), "ls", "-F" }
                   : new String[] { "/bin/ls", "-ld" };
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Though Max's answer covers the actual place where it's being referred. Let me give a brief background on why it needs it on Windows -

From Hadoop's Confluence Page itself -

> Hadoop requires native libraries on Windows to work properly -that
>   includes accessing the file:// filesystem, where Hadoop uses some
>   Windows APIs to implement posix-like file access permissions.
>
> This is implemented in HADOOP.DLL and WINUTILS.EXE.
>
> In particular, %HADOOP_HOME%\BIN\WINUTILS.EXE must be locatable

And , I think you should be able to run both Spark and Hadoop on Windows.