java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions'
I am trying to to wordcount opeartion using hadoop. Hadoop is configured and I can see datanode, namenode, resourcemanager, and nodemanager running. I am using hadoop version 3.4.0 and Java version 8. However, when I paste this command:
C:\hadoop\sbin>hadoop jar C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.4.0.jar wordcount /input /output_dir

This is the error I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsSecurityDescriptor.fromAttribute(WindowsSecurityDescriptor.java:358)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:492)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:136)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempDirectory(TempFileHelper.java:173)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory(Files.java:950)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:245)


Hadoop only supports GNU/Linux, it doesn't work on Windows.

@Mark That is not correct

@OneCricketeer The Hadoop documentation explicitly specifies it isn't supported. Sure, you might get unsupported things to work, but that that is clearly not the case here. The exception message is the result of Hadoop using a PosixFilePermission converted to a FileAttribute, passed to java.nio.Files.createTempDirectory.

@MarkRotteveel How do you define "support"? The ASF isn't an enterprise "support" entity. The software isn't "compiled" for Windows doesn't mean it won't "work"... Specifically, a Windows compiled hadoop.dll + having a winutils.exe shim to remap Unix permissions to windows will fix that problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57941354/2308683

You're getting an internal Java error starting here, so not related to Hadoop...
at java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory(Files.java:950)
Note - the latest Hadoop version supports Java 11, not Java 8. And if that doesn't work, I'd suggest using a proper Linux environment like WSL2 or a VM, not trying to run Hadoop on Windows, since it isn't designed to be.
Additionally, not many people use plain MapReduce anymore when Flink or Spark are much better processing engines.

It is a Hadoop problem, because it is passing a - for Windows - invalid FileAttribute, and that is explicitly documented as throwing an exception. However, Hadoop only supports GNU/Linux (see Supported Platforms, so this is basically expected.

@Mark "Support" there means for development and Apache builds. I've seen people run Hadoop successfully in Windows Server environments

I was facing this same issue, solved it by downgrading hadoop to 3.3.6. I think 3.4.0 is not compatible with windows.

What Java version were you using with Hadoop 3.4.0.

Oracle JDK 8 and hadoop 3.3.6

It does work, just need to add winutils , hadoop.cmd from this link: https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-3.3.6/bin
in %HADOOP_HOME%/bin
